# Sturm-Liouville Problem

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

Given the following BVP
$$-(e^x Y'(x))'=\lambda e^x Y(x), \quad 0<x<\pi$$
$$Y(0)=0, Y(\pi)=0$$

I have found that the eigenfunctions are
$Y_n(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\sin{nx}$

and the eigenvalues are $\lambda_n=\frac{1}{4}+n^2$

We check whether the eigenfunctions are orthogonal by calculating the inner product$\langle f,g\rangle_2=\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) \,dx $

```
\[Lambda][n_] = 1/4 + n^2;
Y[x_, n_] = Exp[-1/2*x]*Sin[n*x]
Integrate[Y[x, 1]*Y[x, 2], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

It is not zero, so it is not orthogonal.

Normalizing eigenfunctions to the new inner product by weight

The norm $||f||_{\mu}=\int_{0}^{1} \mu(x)f(x)g(x) \,dx$ is now defined

```
norm[n_] = Sqrt[Integrate[Exp[x]*Y[x, n]^2, {x, 0, Pi}]]
Simplify[%, n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]
X[x_, n_] = Y[x, n]/norm[n];
Integrate[Exp[x]*X[x, 1]*X[x, 2], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

So the normalized eigenfunctions are orthogonal to the new inner product with weight

**Expansion to the eigenfunctions in terms of the inner product by weight**

We define the function

```
f[x_]=x*(Pi-x)
pic1=Plot[f[x],{x,0,1},PlotStyle->{Thick},PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

the coefficients of the expansion of g with respect to the normalized eigenfunctions are given

```
A[n_] = Integrate[Exp[x]*f[x]*X[x, n], {x, 0, Pi}]
Simplify[%, n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]
```

We define the partial sums

```
S[x_, N_] := Sum[A[n]*X[x, n], {n, 1, N}];
fig2 = Plot[S[x, 5], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
fig3 = Plot[S[x, 10], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Green}]
fig4 = Plot[S[x, 20], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}]
Show[fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is the procedure I am following correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have coded as :

```
\[Lambda][n_] = 1/4 + n^2;
```

`Y[x_, n_] = Exp[-1/2*x]*Sin[n*x]`
`Integrate[Y[x, 1]*Y[x, 2], {x, 0, Pi}]`

But with the check for orthogonality, the integrand was not multiplied by the weight function.
So change the last command to :

`Integrate[Exp[x]*Y[x, 1]*Y[x, 2], {x, 0, Pi}]`

There seems to be  a typo in one of the  commands for graphing

```
Show[fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4]
```

--
Actually , you mean

```
Show[pic1, fig2, fig3, fig4]
```

--

Rest of the calculations are fine.

Comment: This may be more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.